# Is there a similar flag like ln -sh from Mac osX for linux to skip over any file that is already symlinked?

Tags: unix, symlink

e.g. from the Mac man pages:

```
 man ln 


     -h     If the NewLinkFile (or directory) is a symbolic link, do not follow
            it.  This is most useful with the -f option, to replace a symlink
            which can point to a directory.
```

I am writing a script which once a day iterates over hundreds of files and symlinks them all and then periodically through out the day checks for new files and symlinks them. Would be great to use this -h check or something similar as at the moment it is done very awkwardly.

Comment: Sounds like `-T`. `mkdir dir; ln -s dir DIR; touch file; ln -fsT file DIR` will remove `DIR` and re-create as a symlink to `file` instead of creating a (broken) symlink inside the `DIR` -> `dir` directory.

Comment: A more precise equivalent is probably `-n`, but `-T` is safer.

Answer (score 0):

A GNU equivalent of the BSD `ln -sh` is `ln -sn`.

But GNU's `ln -sT` is safer, because it will skip both symbolic links and directories.

Compare:

```
cd "$(mktemp -d)"
mkdir bin
for d in bin usr etc; do ln -sn "/$d" "$d"; done
   # will create a bin/bin -> /bin symlink
```

vs.

```
cd "$(mktemp -d)"
mkdir bin
for d in bin usr etc; do ln -sT "/$d" "$d"; done

ln: failed to create symbolic link 'bin': File exists
```